# Why `supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount` is empty after `add()` fragment to stack

Tags: android, fragment-backstack

In Android app (Kotlin) I have `Activity` with `container` what have `fragment A` in it.
On user interaction, I am adding `fragment B` to `container` by:

```kotlin
supportFragmentManager.commit {
        add(container, fragmentB, tag)
    }
```

Why when I go back in stack by hitting hardware back button (calls `onBackPressed()` in activity) the `supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount` is zero?

Do I need to also call `addToBackStack()` in transaction to be able to intercept back behavior and decide if I want to go back or not?

Will `add() + addToBackStack()` in transaction and `supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()` in `onBackPressed()` method cause re-init of the `fragment A`?